# UIImage returns nil on segue push

Tags: swift, xcode, image, parsing, null

I have an image URL that needs to be parsed and displayed. The URL exists, but returns nil.

It successfully parses in the `cellForRowAt` function by calling **cell.recipeImage.downloadImage(from: (self.tableViewDataSource[indexPath.item].image))**
With this line the image displays. However, it doesn't exist when calling it in `didSelectRowAt`

RecipeTableViewController.swift

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let Storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let resultsVC = Storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ResultsViewController") as! ResultsViewController

    // Information to be passed to ResultsViewController

    if (tableViewDataSource[indexPath.item] as? Recipe) != nil  {
        if isSearching {
            resultsVC.getTitle = filteredData[indexPath.row].title
            //resultsVC.imageDisplay.downloadImage(from: (self.filteredData[indexPath.row].image))
        } else {
            resultsVC.getTitle = tableViewDataSource[indexPath.row].title
            // Parse images
            resultsVC.imageDisplay.downloadImage(from: (self.tableViewDataSource[indexPath.row].image))
        }
    }

    // Push to next view
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(resultsVC, animated: true)
}

extension UIImageView {
func downloadImage(from url: String) {
    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data,response,error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
            return
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.sync {
            self.image = UIImage(data: data!)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
}
```

ResultsViewController.swift

```
class ResultsViewController: UIViewController {

var getTitle = String()
var getImage = String()

@IBOutlet weak var recipeDisplay: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var imageDisplay: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    recipeDisplay.text! = getTitle

}
...
}
```

Returns the error

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Most likely `viewDidLoad` of the controller is not called yet and `imageDisplay` is not connected, that means it's `nil` and causes the crash.

Comment: In which line it's crashing?

Comment: resultsVC.imageDisplay.downloadImage(from: (self.tableViewDataSource[indexPath.row].image)) is the line that crashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling view-related code on views that haven't been initialized yet. Remember, IBOutlets are implicitly unwrapped properties, so if you try to access them before they're initialized they'll force-unwrap and crash. So it's not that the UIImage is coming up nil, it's that recipeDisplay is nil and is getting force unwrapped.

The idiomatic iOS thing to do is to hand a view model of some sort (an object or a struct) to the view controller, and then let it do the work with that item once it has finished loading.

So, in you didSelect method, you could create your view model (which you'd need to define) and hand it off like this:

```
let title = filteredData[indexPath.row].title
let imageURL = self.tableViewDataSource[indexPath.row].image
let viewModel = ViewModel(title: title, imageURL: imageURL)
resultsVC.viewModel = viewModel
```

And then in your resultsVC, you'd do something like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if let vm = viewModel {
        recipeDisplay.text = vm.title
        downloadImage(from: vm.imageURL)
    }
}
```

So in your case all you'd need to do is hand those strings to your VC (you can wrap them up in a view model or hand them off individually) and then in that VC's `viewDidLoad()` that's where you'd call `downloadImage(from:)`. That way there's no danger of calling a subview before that subview has been loaded.

One last note: Your download method should be a little safer with its use of the `data` and `error` variables, and its references to self. Remember, avoid using `!` whenever you don't absolutely have to use it (use optional chaining instead), and unless you have a really good reason to do otherwise, always use `[weak self]` in closures.

I'd recommend doing it like this:

```
func downloadImage(from url: String) {
    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { [weak self] (data,response,error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
            return
        }
        if let data = data {
            DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                self?.image = UIImage(data: data)
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Update: Because the 'view model' concept was a little too much at once, let me explain.

A view model is just an object or struct that represents the presentation data a screen needs to be in a displayable state. It's not the name of a type defined by Apple and isn't defined anywhere in the iOS SDK. It's something you'd need to define yourself. So, in this case, I'd recommend defining it in the same fine where you're going to use it, namely in the same file as ResultsViewController.

You'd do something like this:

```
struct ResultsViewModel {
  let title: String
  let imageURL: String
}
```

and then on the ResultsViewController, you'd create a property like:

`var viewModel: ResultsViewModel?`

or if you don't like dealing with optionals, you can do:

`var viewModel = ResultsViewModel(title: "", imageURL: "")`

OR, you can do what you're already doing, but I'd *highly* recommend renaming those properties. `getTitle` sounds like it's doing something more besides just holding onto a value. `title` would be a better name. Same criticism goes for `getImage`, with the additional criticism that it's also misleading because it sounds like it's storing an image, but it's not. It's storing an image url. `imageURL` is a better name.

Comment: This was helpful! I'm a little confused with where the `ViewModel` is coming from. When I implement this, it shows an error saying "Use of unresolved identifier 'ViewModel'"

Comment: Yeah, like I said, you’d need to define it yourself.

Comment: I think the `ViewModel` is referencing the `ResultsViewController`. So I changed it to `ResultsViewController` and it returns the error: incorrect argument labels in call (have 'title:imageURL:', expected 'nibName:bundle:'). When I do this, there's an argument type error with bundle and string

Comment: I tried defining `ViewModel` several ways, including with the `XMLParser` model and receive errors on all of them. I'm relatively new to swift, and not sure exactly how to define this, or where I should get it from. The help above was a great reference though

Comment: I'm not sure you're understanding what is meant by "define." When one says "define," it means create a new type and define what it is. So, somewhere in this file, write something like:
`struct ViewModel { let title: String    let imageURL: String }`

Comment: Sorry, it's hard to do multi-line stuff in a comment.

Comment: Updated my answer to explain better.

Comment: Yeah thanks! My viewmodel was set up slightly different but I was able to get everything working. Solution helped

Comment: Excellent. Glad to hear it. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, the app is getting crashed at this line:

> recipeDisplay.text! = getTitle

If it is, obviously this is not the proper way to do it. Just remove the force unwrapping because the text on the label here is nil by default. Force referencing a nil value will crash the app.

> recipeDisplay.text = getTitle

UPDATED:
- Let's make sure that you wired the label and the outlets properly. Connect ti to the VC, not the File Owner.

Comment: No, it's not crashing in this line unless the outlet is not connected.

Comment: @vadian yeah. True. I've tried. Looks like if you have it connected to the UI label on the storyboard, the text will be empty instead of nil. So it seems the post author messed up the outlet connections.

Comment: Actually it crashes in the first view controller.

Comment: Oh well. So that's definitely the `imageDisplay` on the `resultVC` is nil. because its `viewDidLoad` has not gotten called yet.

Comment: It's crashing on the line: resultsVC.imageDisplay.downloadImage(from: (self.tableViewDataSource[indexPath.row].image))